# UIDatepicker and a textField

Tags: iphone

i wont to use a datepickerview and a texfield.
i use it like thise, when i touch the textfiled the datepicker apears ( textfield.inputview=...) but i want when i select a date in the pickerview, it should appear in the textfield, how to do this please ??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will need to implement delegate for UITextField and in its - `(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` write following code.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
```

// here you can write code for setting the center of datePicker.
        return NO;
    }

After this you will have to add action methods for picker change event in this method you will set `textField` text from picker value.

```
NSDateFormatter *datePickerFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [datePickerFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]; //here specify your format..
    yourTextField.text = [datePickerFormat stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
[datePickerFormat release];
```

thanks,

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have do this but i have a problem whit the year ( it is not the good year witch appear in the textfield). i have done the same with you exempt  setDateForma:@"JJ/MM/AAAA".

Comment: Did you change  date format?  use @"dd-MM-yyyy" or @"dd/MM/yyyy"